# Delete Pointer in C++ got me confused

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

```
**struct ListNode {
        int val;
      ListNode *next;
         ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
     };
ListNode* Merge(ListNode* list1, ListNode* list2){//list1 2; list2 4
    ListNode* result = new ListNode(0);
    ListNode* travel = result;
    while(list1 || list2){
        cout << "hereWhile" << endl;
        //cout << list1->val << list2->val << endl;
        if(!list1){
            travel->val = list2->val;
            list2 = list2->next;
            travel->next = new ListNode(0);
            travel = travel->next;
        }
        else if(!list2){
            travel->val = list1->val;
            list1 = list1->next;
            travel->next = new ListNode(0);
            travel = travel->next;
        }
        else{
            if(list1->val <= list2->val){
                travel->next = new ListNode(0);
                travel->val = list1->val;
                list1 = list1->next;
                travel = travel->next;
            }
            else{
                travel->next = new ListNode(0);
                travel->val = list2->val;
                list2 = list2->next;
                travel = travel->next;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "travel at the end: " << (travel == result->next->next) << endl;
    delete result->next->next;
    //delete travel;
    cout << travel->val << endl;
    cout << result->val << endl;
    cout << result->next->val << endl;
    cout << "val: " << result->next->next->val << " end" << endl;

    return NULL;
}**
```

in my case, the above delete method never works.

I have updated my whole code in order to provide more details. This is part of implementing a MergeSort by linked list. And my testcase is this recursion and this Merge function is list1 = {2} and list2 = {4} , so the Merge function is designed to return the head of a linked list {2,4} which has a size of two nodes.

In my code above, I declared a new node to travel->next in each of my if statement and I move travel one step further. Hence after the while loop, my linked list becomes {2,4,0} and I have a pointer "travel" pointing to ListNode{0}. However, it cannot be deleted! I have tried both by "delete result->next->next" and "delete travel" but it can still return result->next->next->val, which is 0! (my last cout statement)

WHY?

I declared this new ListNode (which is a struct) in my heap memory. And I want to delete this ListNode out of the while loop. But my delete never works. Maybe the travel was in heap in the brackets, but came out as stack memory after the while loop because I declare the dynamic memory in my loop?

Comment: Please show the rest of your code.

Comment: What makes you think the delete is failing?

Comment: please insert complete function or at least show more context

Comment: Objects in C/C++ never move.

Comment: you loop and perform many new's and only one delete, that is at least a memory leak

Comment: I have seen moving objects in C++

Comment: your pointer party in this function is creazy

Comment: @piotruś really? (or is it a pun on `std::move()`)

Comment: I'm just guessing, because I don't see the rest of the code, but maybe the destructor (`ListNode::~ListNode`) tries to `delete next`, but `next` is not initialized to zero in the constructor. To fix this just initialize `next` to zero in the constructor.

Comment: please, use `shared_ptr`/`unique_ptr` or even `auto_ptr` (for C++03), not raw pointer

Comment: my code has just been updated! Any help will be strongly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

use this in the loop to prevent memory leak

```
<pointer to struct for list2> tmp1 = list2; 
list2 = list2->next; 
delete tmp1;
<pointer to struct for travel> tmp2 = travel; travel = travel->next;
delete tmp2;
```

Comment: @Elazar I don't think so. what happens if "some struct" has destructor?

Comment: ok, considering destructors, the edited version will be better, I guess

Answer (score 0):

I have some questions.

1. Do you want to remove the whole list of travel or a single node?
2. What is the initialize value for travel?
3. you are checking the list1, but not using it inside the loop. Give more details about it.

I assume you need to delete the whole list of travel (list1), and travel is iterator of list1.

```
travel = list1;
while(list1 != NULL)
{
    list1 = list1->next;
    delete travel;
    travel = list1->next;
}
```

Comment: I gave my answer according to my assumption. If my assumptions are wrong, give more details. It will help to figure out the issue.